# Solve this equation

Tags: calculus

I am thinking a problem and am stuck with a mathematical issue.

I can't solve this equation:

$$-ln(10)=ln(n)+n/400$$

Where need to find n.

Would you help me?

Comment: Hint : $n=0.1$  works fine .$$see$$https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bpmuc3g1bf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "elementary" solution: you need the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).  The solution is 
$ n = 400 W(1/4000)$.

EDIT: This is approximately $0.09997500936$.

Comment: [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) added.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use Lambert function, consider
$$f(x)=\log(x)+\frac x{400}+\log(10)$$ $$f'(x)=\frac 1 x+\frac 1{400}$$ So the first derivative is always positive and then only one root to the equation.

By inspection $f(\frac 1{e^2})>0$ and $f(\frac 1{e^3})<0$ and  making the root between $\frac 1{e^3}$ and $\frac 1{e^2}$. Since the second derivative is always negative, start at the lower bound in order to avoid overshoots of the solution (Darboux theorem) and then apply Newton method starting using $x_0=\frac 1{e^3}$. The iterates would then be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.04978706837 \\
 1 & 0.08449879466 \\
 2 & 0.09871032079 \\
 3 & 0.09996697822 \\
 4 & 0.09997500905 \\
 5 & 0.09997500937
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.

**Edit**

Sooner or later, you will learn that, for approximating function, Padé approximants are much better than Taylor series. Let us consider the simplest built around $x=e^{-5/2}$ and look for the zero of the numerator. You would get
$$x=\frac 1 {e^{5/2}}-\frac{\left(1+400 e^{5/2}\right) \left(1-1000 e^{5/2}+400 e^{5/2} \log
   (10)\right)}{e^{5/2} \left(1+1000 e^{5/2}-40000 e^5+80000 e^5 \log (10)\right)}$$ which is $\approx 0.100039$.

Now, let us use Taylor series around $x=\frac 1 {10}$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{4000}+\frac{4001}{400} \left(x-\frac{1}{10}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{1}{10}\right)^2\right)$$
Truncating to first order would give $x=\frac{400}{4001} \approx 0.099975$